# Getting the id of a form on onsubmit Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to get the id of a form of which the onsubmit event is triggered. I have lots of forms in a page so i need to do this. I have tried the ones in the test method and all of those return "undefined"

```
<form id="addToBasketForm_39"  title="" method="post" onsubmit="test()">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="39">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="M1kqlhvmIsZr9N8amTF84lwZeTuMgopHchEt4nhs">
            <a id="submit" class="add-to-cart" onclick="$('#addToBasketForm_39').submit()" >
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Sepete Ekle</a>
        </form> 



function test(){
 var formID = $(this).parents("form").attr("id");

//var formID = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
//var formID = $(this).closest("form[id]").attr('id');
alert(formID + ' form submitted');

}
```

Comment: `function test(event) { var formId = event.target.id; }?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to assign to all submit links unobtrusively

Also NEVER use the name or ID `submit` it can easily hide the submit event

Lastly IDs need to be unique, I removed the no longer used ID from the anchor

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add-to-cart").on("click", function(e) { // anything with class add-to-cart
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
    var $form = $(this).closest("form"); // The form this add-to-cart is in
    test($form.attr("id")); // not sure what you want here
    $form[0].submit(); // submit the actual DOM form
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="addToBasketForm_39" title="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="39">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="M1kqlhvmIsZr9N8amTF84lwZeTuMgopHchEt4nhs">
  <a class="add-to-cart" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Sepete Ekle</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer taught me a lot thanks. I have just one question though.. Why not use $form.submit() instead of $form[0].submit  ?

Comment: You can try either. There was some issues using `$form.submit()` so I am making sure the native form is submitted. Try `$form.submit()` and see if it does what you need in the version of jQuery you use

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler instead of ugly inline event handler.

```
$('form').on('submit', test)
```

In the function

```
function test(){
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

---

As per the current code, pass the current element context i.e. `this`

```
<form id="addToBasketForm_39" onsubmit="test(this)">
```

Access the context in the code

```
function test(element){
  console.log(element.id)
}
```

Comment: @rematnarab, You should read mplungjan's answer, I missed anchor on click portion which he has taken care of

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="addToBasketForm_39"  title="" method="post" onsubmit="test(this)">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="39">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="M1kqlhvmIsZr9N8amTF84lwZeTuMgopHchEt4nhs">
            <a id="submit" class="add-to-cart" onclick="$('#addToBasketForm_39').submit()" >
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Sepete Ekle</a>
        </form> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function test(event)
    {
        var id = event.id;
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```